# Insert into two tables using Scope_Identity PHP and SQL Server 2008

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, insert

I am building an online shop website that lets a user buy items online. Once the user clicks on "Confirm Order" the following query runs:

```
$tsql = "DECLARE @NewID INT

    INSERT INTO orders (orderDate, customerID, price_total) VALUES (GETDATE(),'$custID','$totalPrice')

    SELECT @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO order_items (orderID, price) VALUES ('@NewID', '$totalPrice')";

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql);
```

orderID column in "orders" table is a primary key and is auto-incremented. I want to be able to get that orderID that was just inserted in "orders" table and insert it in "order_items" table along with other relevant information.

The record does get added to the "orders" table, but nothing gets added to the "order_items" table. I am not sure if my query is right. I followed several tutorials that explained scope_identity but as I'm very new to sql and php I might have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried printing the query and running it manually?  Doing so might help you pinpoint what is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about write @NewID and not '@NewID' with apostrophes...

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO order_items (orderID, price) VALUES ('@NewID', '$totalPrice')";
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO order_items (orderID, price) VALUES (@NewID, '$totalPrice')";
```

@NewID is sql variable not a parameter you are passing in.